# ASP.NET conditional validation based on user selection

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently building a form in ASP.NET MVC 4 which allows the user to apply with his team to a competition. The form contains a radio button which is used to determine the number of members of a team(can be 1, or 2).

My model consists of the following tables:

Team, TeamMembers(has a foreign key referencing id from Team)

So a simple master detail relationship.

What I have built so far is a form which enables the user to apply with 2 members. My problem is that validation fires on the form fields for the other user, preventing him from applying with only 1 member. I don't know how to tell ASP.NET to not validate these fields both on client and server side if the radio button is 1(for 1 team member).

How it currently works is that when the user clicks on radio button 1, the part of the form pertaining to team member 2 is faded out. If he clicks on radio button 2, this form is faded in.

These are my ViewModels:

Team ViewModel:

```
public class TeamViewModel
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Naziv tima je obavezan")]
        [DisplayName("Naziv tima")]
        public string Naziv { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Broj članova")]
        public int BrojClanova { get; set; }
        public int AccessCode { get; set; }
        public List<TeamMemberViewModel> Members { get; set; }

    }
```

The team member ViewModel:

```
public class TeamMemberViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ime je obavezno")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Ime se može sastojati samo od slova")]
        [DisplayName("Ime člana")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Prezime je obavezno")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Prezime se može sastojati samo od slova")]
        [DisplayName("Prezime člana")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Općina je obavezna")]
        [DisplayName("Općina")]
        public string Opcina { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Broj telefona je obavezan")]
        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 9, ErrorMessage = "Dužina broja telefona mora biti najmanje 9")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Broj telefona se može sastojati samo od brojeva")]
        [DisplayName("Broj telefona")]
        public string BrojTelefona { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Veličina majice")]
        public string VelicinaMajice { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unos fakulteta/škole je obavezan")]
        [DisplayName("Fakultet/Škola")]
        public string Fakultet { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unos emaila je obavezan")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Format emaila nije validan")]
        [DisplayName("Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public TeamViewModel Team { get; set; }
    }
```

This is how my form looks like:

[Form code](http://pastebin.com/zwp92F94)

Form submit is overriden to look like this:

```
var form3 = $('#team-form');
    form3.submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/Home/SubmitTeam',
            data: $('#team-form').serializeArray(),
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                form3.prepend(form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Prijava se procesira...</p>').fadeIn());
            }
        }).
        success(function (data) {

            if (data.Ok) {
                $('#team-form')[0].reset();
                form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Vas tim je prijavljen. Vidimo se!</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
            }
            else {
                form_status.html('<p class="text-danger">Desila se greska. Pokusajte ponovno.</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
            }
        }).
            complete(function () {
                $("#team-form").each(function () { $.data($(this)[0], 'validator', false); });
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#team-form");
            })

    });
```

My controller code:

[Controller code](http://pastebin.com/StrZbmpB)

If you need anymore info please let me know.

Comment: One option would be to use a view model that represent what you want - e.g. `public string Member1FirstName`, `public string Member2FirstName` and then apply a `[RequiredIf]` validation attribute to the properties associated with the 2nd team member. But a better solution would be to dynamically add new team members as required (what if you wanted to add 3 team members?).

Comment: Hey Matsura, you should avoid doing complete code dumps like this.. just reduce your models to the relevant properties, include the markup (form) in the question (regarding the reduced models). the controller and form.submit may be unnecessary, as the validation logic generates client-side scripts/logic that apply to property change events, right?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I just wanted to give enough details regarding what I wanted to do. The form submit is to add the little progress wheel showing the request is being processed and output a simple text message if it fails.

2 Members are currently maximum with no plans to extend in the future as it is a one - time competition. Is it possible to keep this ViewModel like it is? If not which modifications are needed?

Comment: that's fine.. the solution is actually fairly simple, it goes to the question of.. how is validation applied on a particular property and how is a property determined to be valid? well, you're applying a [Required] (RequiredAttribute) to the property. On the Attribute, there is an `IsValid` method, which by defaut, simply checks if the value is empty or not.. thus you need to override the control/property validation.

Comment: @Brett Caswell Can you explain a bit further?

Comment: @Matsura, I'll put an example together..